# Code to fetch BitBucket repos

Tags: bash, curl, jq

This actually works nicely (we have > 2k repos) but I would really like it to start producing results right away as soon as it has any. Mostly so it seems faster than it is (by being more responsive).

```
   bbrepos(){
        #clone[1] is ssh using a filter made the escaping really ugly. 
        #If it becomes necessary we can use a jq arg
        # get max number of repos, ceil(repos / 50), then create a page 
        #sequence and curl them all
        local url=https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/twengg
        local project=${1:+"q=project.key=\"$1\""}
        curl -snL  "$url?pagelen=0&page=1" | jq '"$(((\(.size) / 50) + 1 ))"' \
            | xargs bash -c 'eval "echo $1"' _ | xargs seq 1 | xargs -L 1 printf "?pagelen=50&page=%s&${1:-$project}\n" \
            | xargs -I {} -L 1 -P 20 -I {} bash -c 'curl -snL  "$1/$2" | jq -er .values[].links.clone[1].href' _ $url {} \ #clone[1] is ssh
            | sort -u
    }
```

Sample workflow:

```
bbsearch something | xargs -P 20 git clone
```

Alternatively, it might also be handy to have these other workflows:

```
bbsearch something other thing | xargs -P 20 git clone

cat things-to-find.txt | bbsearch | xargs -P 20 git clone
```

Sample payload (it's normally huge, so I stripped it down to what is needed):

```
{
  "pagelen": 1,
  "size": 3054,
  "values": [
    {
      "links": {
        "clone": [
          {
            "href": "https://chb0bitbucket@bitbucket.org/twengg/development-process.git",
            "name": "https"
          },
          {
            "href": "git@bitbucket.org:twengg/development-process.git",
            "name": "ssh"
          }
        ],
        "self": {
          "href": "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/twengg/development-process"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "page": 1,
  "next": "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/twengg?page=2"
}
```

Comment: Please describe the flow appropriately and add a sample fragment of `.values[].links` structure

Comment: This could be a great question if it described the work flow. Who doesn't want to speed up their workflow. A real example might also be nice.

Answer (score 3):

#### `eval` is evil

Always look for ways to avoid `eval`.

Relevant snippet from the posted code:

> ```
> curl -snL  "$url?pagelen=0&page=1" \
>     | jq '"$(((\(.size) / 50) + 1 ))"' \
>     | xargs bash -c 'eval "echo $1"' _
> ```

The code uses `jq` to create a formatted expression to evaluate by Bash,
with `.size` injected in the middle of the expression.

A better way to achieve the same thing would be to make `jq` simply output the variable itself, and then write the expression in Bash:

```
curl -snL  "$url?pagelen=0&page=1" \
    | jq -r .size \
    | xargs bash -c 'echo $((($1 / 50) + 1))' _
```

#### Unnecessary pipeline

It's strange to use `xargs` to process one line of input,
and it's strange to spawn another Bash just to evaluate an expression.
There's really no need to force a chain of operations in a single pipeline.

I'd rewrite the above snippet like this:

```
repos_count=$(curl -snL "$url?pagelen=0&page=1" | jq -r .size)
((pages_count = (repos_count / 50) + 1))
```

#### Store positional arguments in variables with descriptive names

It's a mental burden to have to remember what `$1` and `$2` mean.
I'd store them in local variables with descriptive names at the beginning of the function.

#### Avoid `seq`

Is it obsolete, and not available in all systems.
Use a Bash counting loop instead:

```
for ((page = 1; page <= pages_count; page++)); do
    ...
done \
| xargs -L 1 ...
```

#### Break lines in long pipelines

It's easier to read code when there's one statement per line.
This is especially true when a line is so long you have to scroll to the right to see it.
So instead of this:

> ```
> | xargs bash -c 'eval "echo $1"' _ | xargs seq 1 | xargs -L 1 printf "?pagelen=50&page=%s&${1:-$project}\n" \
> | xargs -I {} -L 1 -P 20 -I {} bash -c 'curl -snL  "$1/$2" | jq -er .values[].links.clone[1].href' _ $url {} \ #clone[1] is ssh
> | sort -u
> ```

I recommend to write like this:

```
| xargs bash -c 'eval "echo $1"' _ \
| xargs seq 1 \
| xargs -L 1 printf "?pagelen=50&page=%s&${1:-$project}\n" \
| xargs -I {} -L 1 -P 20 -I {} bash -c 'curl -snL  "$1/$2" \
| jq -er .values[].links.clone[1].href' _ $url {} \
| sort -u
```

#### Always double-quote variables used as command line arguments

In `| jq -er .values[].links.clone[1].href' _ $url {}`
you forgot to double-quote `$url`.

Comment: This is good feedback and I will incorporate it - however, it doesn't address how I get this to output immediately more input comes